# Follow Plugin Generatorで生成されるFollowボタンのデザインを変更したい

Tags: javascript, html, css

LinkedInのFollow Plugin Generatorで生成されるFollowボタンを
（https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company）
自社のオウンドメディアであるGlobal Career Siteに埋め込もうと考えています。

Plugin Generatorのサービス上で生成されるボタンは3つのパターン（カウントあり（縦）、カウントあり（横）、カウントなし）でありますが、こちらのFollowボタンのデザインに準拠する必要はあるのでしょうか。Generatorで生成されたFollowボタン以外を利用することはできるのでしょうか。

デザイン変更にあたって何らかの制約条件があるのであれば把握をしたうえで開発要否を判断したいという目的です。

Answer (score 1):

**注意: この回答は 2018 年 7 月現在の情報に基づくものです。現在も正しいとは限りません。また、利用規約の解釈が間違っている可能性もあります。より厳密には、LinkedIn 社に問い合わせる方が良いでしょう。**

プラグインの [Terms of Use](https://developer.linkedin.com/legal/plugin-terms-of-use) の "Restrictions on Use" (ご利用にあたっての制限事項) には、以下のように書かれています。

> The Plugin license is subject to the following restrictions on use: (中略) (b) you may not obscure or disable any element of the Plugins; (中略). Subject to the limited license granted to you above, the Plugins and the Plugin Content may not be copied, modified, deleted, reproduced, republished, posted, transmitted, sold, offered for sale, or redistributed without LinkedIn’s prior written approval in each instance. (後略)

<sup>(LinkedIn Plugin Terms of Use, revised on April 23, 2018 より引用)</sup>

つまりこのプラグインを使うにあたって、生成された要素を削除したり改変したりすることは特別の許可が無い限り利用規約違反となります。